# Issue in "Accessing S3 bucket from ElasticBeanstalk using Docker Json file"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker

When I try to deploy my code in Docker Hub from ElasticBeanstalk, I am getting the following error. 
The problem is with the S3 bucket endpoint. What is the right way to specify the endpoint for S3 bucket in the Json template below.

**ERROR:**

```
<Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>srini-bucket</BucketName>
<RequestId>87B1CFBA66EAC80B</RequestId>     
<HostId>XSzOT/Efj0nFK8Qks6XpH6HBthCA7j9q8M42eRiqrgBqvM3Nl4f4rt73r+JhUao= </HostId>
</Error>
Failed to download authentication credentials docker/.dockercfg from srini-bucket(Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

**JSON TEMPLATE**

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
 "Image": {
      "Name": "champ45/tomstar",
      "Update": "true"
          },
 "Authentication": {
      "Bucket": "srini-bucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Key": "dockerFolder/.dockercfg"
         },
 "Ports": [
     {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
      }
        ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think specified bucket name is wrong in the JSON template. `.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com` is unnecessary.

Please read `Using Images from a Private Repository` section in the following documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html